# SSL and Php pagination and the error message

Tags: php, ssl

I got problem to load next(new page generated by php). 
I got the Error message in IE (Do you want to view only the webpage content that delivered security ?)

I´m 100 % sure that my SSL page does not content any link or stuff from none SSL site.
This happen just in IE.

Here is the example web address I  have problem:

```
https://www.mysite.com/online.php#/page/2
```

Can somebody tell me why ?

Comment: 100% sure eh? Better make 110% sure then that there are no scripts, libraries, images or other external links that are not https://.

Comment: I´m sure 110% I have test it with the SSL online test.
And I have also double checked everywhere.

Comment: go to your /page/2 and inspect all the elements in the network tab of your browser's developer console.

Comment: I did it..can not see any error there. I just don´t understand this..why.

Comment: There won't be any errors there, but there might be resources loaded insecurely.

Comment: I have also pass https://www.mysite.com/online.php#/page/2  into this web site : http://www.whynopadlock.com

Everything seems ok.  This happen just only in IE. So strange

Comment: I remove this file jquery-ias.min.js and tried reload the page and the error message is gone. But i need to use this file. I have looked around in side and see no none ssl links.

Comment: load a copy of it locally, or load it with https://

Comment: I load it with https://

Comment: It actually because of jquery.min.js but I don+t know where.